# Create figures similar to Rect

Tags: android, android-studio, rect

I recently decided to create an interactive map in which you clicked on an icon and a certain information was opened in Android. I decided to take the step and see how to use icons to use an area. But I ran into the problem that the icon was square but the area no longer serves me as it used to with the RECT class of android.graphics. There is some way that I thermite create some figure apart from the rectangle and check with Rect.contains(int x, int y)

```
Rect numero_1=new Rect(801,395,831,425);
if(numero_1.contains((int)xPercentage,(int)yPercentage)){

}
```

Comment: What your problem? Using rect as the size of an icon? You actually look to consider all icons to be square (xpercentage, yPercentage) you need to check the numer_1 rect if it contains touchEvent.getX/getY, if you have scroll you have to add the ammount to it also

Comment: I use a library that allows me to detect the pulse. The thing is that the area I want to detect the pulse is not a rectangle, it is a totally asymmetric figure. Then the rectum is no good to me to delimit the area.

Comment: Oh.. you looking for intersection into polygons (a lined path) don't remember a link for that but search for it.